# SQL Server stored procedure loop through table

Tags: sql-server, for-loop, stored-procedures

I have created a procedure like this:

```
USE [Solstein]
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SolsteinSecuritiesMap
    @SecId int,
    @SecurityKey nvarchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Solstein.dbo.tabela (KiskiSecID, SecurityKey)
    VALUES (@SecId, @SecurityKey)
END
```

To check that it works I ran

```
execute dbo.SolsteinSecuritiesMap @SecId = 227, @SecurityKey = 'TRIP'
```

What I would like to do is write a procedure that will loop through the following table:

[image]

and insert values in the way I specified above.

The code that generated the table above is as follows:

```
select a.secId, b.SecurityKey
from gmd.sm.tblSecurityMaster a
join solstein.dbo.missing_sec_map b on a.BBGTicker = b.BBGTicker;
```

Comment: Why do you want to loop at all? SQL is a set based language, you should be aiming to use set based methods.

Comment: So you want to insert all the records from the select statement shown into the Solstein.dbo.tabela table?  If so, then just put the select after the insert statement.

Comment: An `INSERT` can accept a `SELECT` as its source of data. Using an sproc for a single row and looping over it would be a bad call; either don't use the sproc and just write out the `INSERT`, or (if non-trivial business logic is going to be added that's not shown here) use an sproc that accepts a table-valued parameter and fill that first.

Comment: DON'T use three-part object names (<database>.<schema>.<table>) without a very good reason. Here you have no good reason since your procedure is created and exists within the same database as the table it uses. Learn good habits.

Answer (score 0):

The following has worked for me, no for loop was needed:

```
USE [Solstein]

GO

CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.SolsteinSecuritiesMap
               
AS

BEGIN

insert into dbo.tabela(KiskiSecID, SecurityKey)
select a.secId, b.SecurityKey
from gmd.sm.tblSecurityMaster a
join dbo.missing_sec_map b
on a.BBGTicker=b.BBGTicker;

END
```